# .Net Framework Security Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, hta

I’ve got an issue that was reported by one of our customers: On Windows 7 machines, our program, which is a dll that’s hosted in a webpage (and connects to a web service to retrieve data), runs without any issues, unless the user first runs certain 3rd party software, then launches our program…

When this happens, the user gets the following message, and the program (and message) lockup:

```
Application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
security policy. To grant this application the required permission,
contact your system administrator, or use the Microsoft.NET
Framework Configuration tool.

Request for permission of type
'System.Security.Permission.UIPermission, mscorlib.
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKey=b77a6c561934e099' failed.
```

Any ideas why this would only happen if the other program is running when our program is launched?

Edit 1:

Our software is hosted on one of the client's servers, and is run through their intranet. The client's machines are caspol'd to run stuff from the server

Edit 2:

The client is using the dll inside a `.hta`

Comment: could be requiring UAC permissions (i.e more than a standard user permissions). seems the 3rd party software requires elevated permissions. its unclear if this problem happens on your website or the software the customer is running on their desktop??

Comment: @Ahmedilyas Okay, but how/why would that affect our program? As long as their software is not running, our's is fine.

Comment: not sure since I don't know how the program works or the code but have they tried running in complete Admin mode and doing what is normally done to produce the error? if you can run it then it is a permissions thing that is requiring some certain access rights

Comment: @Ahmedilyas I'll look into the UAC possibility, however it may take a few days to hear back from the client...

Comment: no problem - understood. I know how that works :)